# For how long could astronauts stay on the surface of Europa, Jupiter's moon, with our current latest and most advanced spacesuit before dying?

Tags: astronauts, spacesuits, radiation, magnetosphere

Is it possible for astronauts to land on Europa safely?

Given the fact that radiation level on Europa is about 5.4 Sv (or about 540 rem) per day and the temperature is around -260 °F (or about -160 °C).

--> Assume astronauts somehow land successfully on Europa and are  equipped with the latest and most advanced spacesuit as of 2022. For how long could they stay on the Europa's surface before the radiation level and the cold temperature get out of hand and potentially kill them in process?

Comment: "equipped with the latest and most advanced spacesuit version in 2022" – Sadly, the "latest and most advanced spacesuit version in 2022" is basically the same as 1964, when the contract for the Apollo spacesuits was awarded. The EMUs that are used on the ISS are the same ones as the ones used for Shuttle, which are closely related to the ones used on Apollo and Skylab. The effort to develop a successor is so far above budget and behind schedule that it was restarted just this year, but was again awarded to (some of) the same compan(y/ies) that already built the Apollo-Skylab-Shuttle-ISS ones.

Comment: Same for the Russian Orlan: it is essentially from 1967. And if you were hoping to look to China or India: they just bought the Orlan.

Comment: So with the EMUs or the Apollo spacesuits, does it well protected enough for astronauts to spend hours on Europa moon - which has radiation level about 5.4 Sv daily - if they somehow manage to set foot on it?

Comment: [Linking a related post (and comments underneath)](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/27041/40257) discussing this from two of the best experts on this site!

Comment: @ZanMoon-chan different but related (especially to radiation): [Would a Europa lander need radiation shielding similar to Juno?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/18218/12102) and [If colonists burrowed far enough under the ice on Ganymede or Europa, would the ice provide adequate protection for them from Jupiter's radiation?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/25374/12102) and [How would a robotic landing on an icy moon like Europa differ from landings on the Moon, Mars, Venus, Jupiter, Titan, asteroids, comets?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/13198/12102)

Comment: and [What would it take to survive the radiation on the surface of Ganymede?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/43426/12102)

Comment: Regarding the radiation issue it seems we need to kinds of information: Radiation levels at different regions of Europa - they seem to be vastly different, but I couldn't find a proper map. And the composition of the radiation, which I also couldn't find.

Comment: @asdfex Although we know a lot about the structure and processes in Jupiter's magnetosphere, there's still a lot that we don't know, and we don't have good detailed maps of the various kinds of particles & radiation and their energies. But there's some relevant info in [The in-situ exploration of Jupiter’s radiation belts](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10686-021-09801-0).

Comment: @JörgWMittag Aren't the Shuttle / ISS suits very different from the Apollo ones?

Answer (score 6):

### About Four Minutes

The OSHA safety limit for radiation is 5 REM per year. With a surface radiation is 540 REM, you'd hit the OSHA limit at about 3 minutes 45 seconds.

Space suits provide negligible radiation protection. To understand how little, consider the [tenth thickness of lead](https://www.osha.gov/ionizing-radiation/introduction/shielding-layer-examples) is 4 cm (1.5 inches). For a space suit to increase one's stay time from 4 minutes to 40 minutes, it would need to be made of 1.5 inch thick lead plate!

### Or One Day if you're Ruthless

A 6 Sv dose has about a [50% survival rate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acute_radiation_syndrome), assuming you can get medical treatment quickly. (Gy and Sv are equivalent for this kind of rough math.)

So your crew could stay for a day if you're willing to have half of them die on the way home.